# Ace Editor: Disable shadowed line where the cursor is

Tags: javascript, angular, ace-editor

I am using Ace editor and I want to disable shadowed line where the cursor is.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMnN3.png)

I have tried changing themes availables in [Ace Mode Creator](https://ace.c9.io/tool/mode_creator.html) but all have this line shadowed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I found the boolean attribute from the Ace demo here (https://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html).

Is called `Highlight Active Line`

I hope it works for you :)

Comment: Yeah, that's it!

`this.jsonSchema.setHighlightActiveLine(false);`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for:

i.e in chrome theme (https://ace.c9.io/lib/ace/theme/chrome.css) its

```
.ace-chrome .ace_marker-layer .ace_active-line {
    background: none
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard setting that doesn't require changing the theme

```
// e = active editor
e.setHighlightActiveLine(boolean)
```

Most themes have it set active by default. It should be a standard configurable setting to enable or disable it.

Answer (score 0):

in vuejs just add `readonly="true"`  and I think it's

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32866958)